# Unable to use Less-than/greater-than with Datetime in SOQL condition

Tags: apex, soql, where

I am unable to use a Datetime field in a SOQL query:

```
SELECT Status FROM Campaign WHERE LastModifiedDate >= Last_Sync__c;
```

I have a workaround where I create a checkbox formula field which is true when `LastModifiedDate > Last_Sync__c` and use that in the SOQL WHERE clause.

**Is any other workaround without creating an extra field?**

Comment: I believe this "workaround" is the only solution; SOQL does not support WHERE clauses that compare two fields against each other, but rather just a field against a constant (be that a literal or via a binding variable).

Comment: There is another workaround without WHERE clause. Just run for-loop after SOQL and make necessary selection comparing fields in if-clause. You are the one who decides which solution is better: the one that requires new field, or the one that takes more time and queries more rows.

Comment: Given that this is the only clause in the WHERE, I would suggest doing the test in Apex against the results without the WHERE clause isn't a real option, since there is no way to limit the results. To do that you would need to consider making this into a batch process, and then this is only good for up to 50 million rows in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling together my comment and that from Marlia, there are basically two options:

1. Add a formula field as you have suggested. This isn't really a "workaround" as such since what you are trying to do simply isn't supported by SOQL; SOQL only allows fields to be compared with constants, not other fields, be those literal values or binding variables.
2. Remove the WHERE sub-clause that is to perform the comparison and do that comparison in Apex code against the results. This is workable if the SOQL query has other WHERE sub-clauses that would ensure that the number of returned rows would be manageable without this comparison part. Recall that you are limited to 50000 rows per session/transaction (this being shared across all your queries in that session/transaction). If removing this sub-clause would mean this limit would be broken, you would have to move your query and processing into a batch (thus raising the over-all limit to 50 million rows across the entire batch start/execute/finish flow).

Comment: I think i should go with creating one extra field, because that would be less complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue that that "worakround" was the best solution that I found.
It was surprising and strange for me too, but things are strange sometimes...
SOQL has its strengths and weaknesses.